# T-SQL String Replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I need to replace the tag {URL}:

```
DECLARE @PageUrl varchar(200)
DECLARE @Body varchar(MAX)

SET @PageUrl = 'http://www.website.com/site1/site2/pageName.asxp?rid=1232'
SET @Body = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed luctus, 
{URL} enim nec posuere volutpat, neque dui volutpat turpis. '

SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body,'{Url}', CONVERT(varchar,@PageUrl))
PRINT @Body
```

My expected result is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed luctus,
http://www.website.com/site1/site2/pageName.asxp?rid=1232 enim nec posuere volutpat, neque dui volutpat turpis.
```

And the print result is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed luctus,
http://www.website.com/site1/s enim nec posuere volutpat, neque dui volutpat turpis.
```

As you can see the replace function cuts the url string at its 31...

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is not the `replace` method , it is the `convert` method..

You need to either specify the length of the converted type

```
SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body,'{Url}', CONVERT(varchar(200),@PageUrl))
```

or since it is already defined as a varchar just use the variable..

```
SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body,'{Url}', @PageUrl)
```

If you have a look at the [char/vachrar page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

> When n is not specified in a data
>   definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1.
>   When n is not specified when using the
>   CAST and CONVERT functions, the
>   default length is **30**.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify a varchar length:

```
CONVERT(varchar,@PageUrl)
```

guess what the default is? 30, just like you say in the question (the 31st char to the end is missing)

use it like this:

```
CONVERT(varchar(200),@PageUrl)
```

to get all the characters

Answer (score 1):

It's getting cut off at this line:

```
SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body,'{Url}', CONVERT(varchar,@PageUrl))
```

Use this:

```
SET @Body = REPLACE(@Body,'{Url}', CONVERT(varchar(200),@PageUrl))
```